# Using the leftover oven heat

Tags: oven, cleaning, efficiency

I use my oven a lot to bake things and roast vegetables, usually at 350 or 400 F. It stays hot for a while afterwards, and it seems like such a waste to not somehow use that heat. Are there any dishes or kitchen maintenance things I can do with an off-but-still-hot oven?

Comment: Warm up your house in the winter?

Comment: It's simplistic, but it's great way to warm up leftovers, even on the (oven-safe) plate! Also, if you've got a stubborn patch of burnt-on oil on a pan, sprinkle some detergent on it, add water and let it soak in there for a while.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drying herbs is what I'll use residual oven heat for.

Comment: You can use it to dry a lot of other things too. I've worked at some restaurants where we made croutons and dried bread for breadcrumbs in the ovens overnight.

Answer (score 7):

The first thought that came to mind was to make meringues overnight.

[This 'perfect meringue' recipe](http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/wordofmouth/2010/aug/19/how-to-make-perfect-meringue) says to put them in an oven at 200C and then turn the oven off and leave them in until the over is cool.

There is another similar [meringue cookie recipe](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/emeril-lagasse/meringue-cookies-forgotten-kisses-recipe.html) which also states you can leave them in the oven when its off until the morning

And another for [forgotten pudding](http://www.nigella.com/recipes/view/forgotten-pudding-60) which you can just 'forget' in the oven as its off.

So it would seem that this is definately an option

Answer (score 1):

I put my plates in there to warm before plating and serving the food.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use it for cooking food, know that opening the oven door won't heat your house any better than leaving it closed.

I've seen a few folks open it saying they don't want to 'waste the heat', but in reality it will be a slower, more constant source of heat if it's left closed.

Comment: With my oven (and I assume most ovens) the oven runs a fan a long as the oven is hot.  You wouldn't be wasting heat, but depending on how things work out, you might be slightly more efficient if you open the oven door so you don't waste electricity.  Amusingly, this actually means that by opening the door you release less heat into your house (since running the fan produces a minute amount of heat.)

Answer (score 0):

***HOMEMADE BISCUITS***

use a thin enough tin foil round pan, 8 in  ...  (store bought, yes the disposable ones).

Comment: You mean use a disposable pan? Like [this](http://www.amazon.com/Aluminum-Foil-Pie-Pan-Set/dp/B00BJ5A48I/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1405485205&sr=8-4&keywords=8+inch+disposable+pan)?

Comment: I live in Chicago and during the last winter monster storm I had a lot of time on my hands so I spent much of that time doing what I love best... cooking/baking.  Time your recipe first (how long does it take to bake homemade biscuits) ... test YOUR oven too. This is what I did and I learned to bake using different methods (again, for fun for myself).  Best of luck :)

Comment: Why are biscuits a good idea with leftover heat, rather than a fully heated oven? Don't biscuits usually have a higher baking temperature?